# Is it possible for a website to know if i open another browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

Websites can track if i open new tab . Can they track me if i open another browser ?
I researched on internet but i only found information related to tabs so i guess it's not possible.I have seen websites showing that if user is idle and can they tell the same if i haven't closed the browser but i have opened another browser ?

For example i have opened some website on google chrome . If i open Firefox without minimizing the google chrome, will the website on google chrome able to know this ?

Websites cannot use cookies from two browsers so i think they cannot track.

Comment: But they can know that it's you because of the IP address.

Comment: It is possible to track you by ip or if you are logged in.